# Stacked bars in Charts.js from a JSON list of objects

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

i'm trying to create a Charts.js with stacked bars from a json list of objects, with no success...

my json is

```
   [{
    "machine": {
        "machineId": 1,
        "name": "a",
        "description": "aaaaaa",
        "active": true,
        "direction": "IN"
    },
    "realEnergy": 56.99,
    "lastUpdate": "2018-10-16 09:00:00"
 }, {
    "machine": {
        "machineId": 2,
        "name": "ABCD 1",
        "description": "ABCD 1",
        "active": true,
        "direction": "OUT"
    },
    "realEnergy": 62.11,
    "lastUpdate": "2018-10-16 09:00:00"
 }, {
    "machine": {
        "machineId": 1,
        "name": "M1",
        "description": "Machine M1",
        "active": true,
        "direction": "IN"
    },
    "realEnergy": 57.11,
    "lastUpdate": "2018-10-16 09:30:00"
 }, {
    "machine": {
        "machineId": 2,
        "name": "ABCD 1",
        "description": "ABCD 1",
        "active": true,
        "direction": "OUT"
    },
    "realEnergy": 62.14,
    "lastUpdate": "2018-10-16 09:30:00"
 }, {
    "machine": {
        "machineId": 1,
        "name": "M1",
        "description": "Machine M1",
        "active": true,
        "direction": "IN"
    },
    "realEnergy": 58.18,
    "lastUpdate": "2018-10-16 10:00:00"
 }, {
    "machine": {
        "machineId": 2,
        "name": "ABCD 1",
        "description": "ABCD 1",
        "active": true,
        "direction": "OUT"
    },
    "realEnergy": 71.11,
    "lastUpdate": "2018-10-16 10:00:00"
 }, {
    "machine": {
        "machineId": 1,
        "name": "M1",
        "description": "Machine M1",
        "active": true,
        "direction": "IN"
    },
    "realEnergy": 64.11,
    "lastUpdate": "2018-10-16 10:30:00"
 }, {
    "machine": {
        "machineId": 2,
        "name": "ABCD 1",
        "description": "ABCD 1",
        "active": true,
        "direction": "OUT"
    },
    "realEnergy": 72.11,
    "lastUpdate": "2018-10-16 10:30:00"
 }]
```

I would like to have lastUpdate on the labels and stacked realEnergy values for the bars.
I was trying to adopt this json to match Charts.js dataset with no luck.

```
var size = Object.keys(json).length ;
            labels = response.map(function(e) {
                   return e.lastUpdate;
                });
for(var i = 0; i < size; i++){
                 datasetValue[i] = {
                            fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',
                            strokeColor :'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                            label :json[i].machine.name,
                            data : json[i].realEnergy
                        }
            }

var myData = {
                    datasets : datasetValue
                }

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data:  {
                        labels: labels,
                        datasets:myData
                    },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                 stacked: true
                            }],
                            xAxes: [{
                                stacked: true
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });  
        }
```

I can get the labels correctly but no data on it, cannot understand how the dataset values should be created.

Comment: What is the result of console.log(myData);

Comment: Share the relevant aspect of your html as well.

Comment: You can see example of dataset value [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/#creating-a-chart). According to this, you should create 2 datasets (for each machine) and data should be accumulated in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataset's data property is an array of values that will be distributed across the labels (in this case realEnergy value per each lastUpdate). I assume that each dataset should represent particular machine.

Here's the code to generate datasets and labels based on your JSON data:

```
const jsonData = JSON.parse(yourJSONData);
const colors = ['yellow', 'green', 'blue']; // purely optional


const machines = jsonData.reduce((uniqueMachines, record) => {
  // find unique machines that will be base to our datasets
  if (!uniqueMachines.find(machine => machine.machineId === record.machine.machineId))
    uniqueMachines.push(record.machine);
  return uniqueMachines;
}, []);

const lastUpdates = jsonData.reduce((uniqueLastUpdates, record) => {
  // get labels for our chart
  if (!uniqueLastUpdates.find(lastUpdate => lastUpdate === record.lastUpdate))
    uniqueLastUpdates.push(record.lastUpdate);
  return uniqueLastUpdates;
}, []);

const datasets = machines.map((machine, index) => {
  const label = machine.name;
  const backgroundColor = colors[index]; // purely optional
  const data = lastUpdates.map(lastUpdate => {
    const valueRecord = jsonData.find(record => record.machine.machineId === machine.machineId && record.lastUpdate === lastUpdate);
    if (!valueRecord) return 0;  // if value record is not defined, return 0;
    return valueRecord.realEnergy;
  });

  return {
    // here we return dataset
    label,
    backgroundColor,
    data,
    stack: 'main' // here we define the stack
  };
});
```

And here's the final configuration for the chart:

```
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: lastUpdates,
    datasets
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

A working example on the JSFiddle: [click](https://jsfiddle.net/mjv0zf9r/1/)